# Proper use of sep in print

Tags: python, macos, syntax

I am new at python, and I am having problems with the use of sep=.
What I want to do is to not have a space between the number `25` and the `.`

Here is my code and the error I get. I am running this code on MAC OSX El Capitan's Terminal.

code:

```
side = 5
area = side * side
print "The area of a square with side ",side,"is ",area,".",sep=" "
```

Output:

```
print "The area of a square with side ",side,"is ",area,".",sep=" "

                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what python version is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sep` is an argument to the [`print()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), which requires you use Python 3 or use a special `from __future__ import print_function` statement in Python 2 (see the [`print()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print).

The normal plain vanilla [Python 2 `print` *statement*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) (which is what you appear to be using) does not support altering the separator used.

Since the separator is *always* a space, you don't need to specify it here at all:

```
print "The area of a square with side ", side, "is ", area, "."
```

If you wanted to print *without* spaces, use string formatting instead:

```
print "The area of a square with side {} is {}.".format(side, area)
```

If you are using a Python 3 tutorial using `print(foo, bar, baz sep='')` or similar similar syntax, get yourself Python 3 installed, or get yourself a Python 2 specific tutorial instead.

Answer (score 2):

In `python 2.x` print doesn't take arguments because ***print is a statement*** and ***not a function***.

You can use the `print()` function by importing from the `future` module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

As the first import of your `.py` file.

And then ***call*** print (don't omit the parentheses!):

```
# This call is valid by default for Python 3.x
# It is also valid for Python 2 if you import the print_function
print ("The area of a square with side", side, "is", area, ".", sep=" ")
```

---

Alternatively, `Python 2` spacing can be added explicitly by adding it in the string to be printed along with the `+` operator that combines strings:

```
# wrap int objects in str() to convert them to strings.
print "The area of a square with side " + str(side) + " is " + str(area) + "."
```

---

Check your python version (by running `python -V` in your terminal) and *read the right docs* ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked my version and it's Python 2

Comment: You're welcome, Daniel. Accept either Martjins or my answer by pressing the 'tick' symbol to indicate to other users that your issue has been solved.